# mysql command not executing from command prompt

Tags: mysql, command

I am trying to execute a SQL script from windows command prompt without logging into mysql. When I execute the following command no tables get created.

```
c:\STS>mysql --user=root --password=root sts_test1 < ..\sts_database\schema_creation_sql\create_schema.sql > a.out
```

While if I log into mysql using `mysql -u root -p` and then do a `source <filename>` it works.

Not able to diaganose what's wrong....

Answer (score 0):

There is no error but it was a mistake. My SQL file has a statement to create and use a database. So the database `sts_test1` selection got overruled by SQL command to create another one in my SQL script.

So, just for extra piece of info , one does not need to specify `--database=<db_name>` if the sql command for the same is present in the .SQL script.